# Passing empty or blank values from Excel data to SQL Server using VBA

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba

How to pass empty or blank values in Excel to SQL Server using VBA?

When my code reads a blank cell the next succeeding cell will be blank too even if it has data.

I tried to put null when the cell is empty but I'm having trouble with the date since my data type for date column in SQL Server is date so it cant read the "null" as date.

Also I get a run-time error ("Incorrect syntax near ','") in my SQL query.

```vb
Public Sub UploadData()

    Dim count As Long
    Dim start As Integer
    Dim i As Long
    Dim con As ADODB.Connection

    Set con = New ADODB.Connection
    con.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=10.206.88.119\BIWFO;" & _
                      "Initial Catalog=TESTDB;" & _
                      "Uid=user; Pwd=pass;"
    
    Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
    Dim pm As ADODB.Parameter

    If MsgBox("This will IMPORT everything! Are you sure?", vbYesNo) = vbNo Then Exit Sub
    
    Dim rng As Range:  Set rng = Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlToRight).End(xlDown))
    Dim row As Range
    
    count = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).row

    i = 2

    OpenStatusBar

    Do While i <= count
 
        For Each row In rng.Rows

            RequestID = row.Cells(1).Value
            IssuingCountryName = row.Cells(2).Value
            ProgramStructure = row.Cells(3).Value
            LineOfBusinessName = row.Cells(4).Value
            RequestGrossPremiumAmount = row.Cells(5).Value
            RequestCollectionCurrencyName = row.Cells(6).Value
            Clientname = row.Cells(7).Value
            ROServiceContact = row.Cells(8).Value
            RequestEffectiveDate = row.Cells(9).Value
            RequestReleaseDate = row.Cells(10).Value
            OriginalRequestReleaseDate = row.Cells(11).Value
            RequestType = row.Cells(12).Value
            RequestStatus = row.Cells(13).Value
            RequestRejectDate = row.Cells(14).Value
            RequestRejectReason = row.Cells(15).Value
            RequestCorrectionDate = row.Cells(16).Value
            RequestAcceptedDate = row.Cells(17).Value
            RequestLocalBookDate = row.Cells(18).Value
            PolicyIssuedDate = row.Cells(19).Value
            IOAccountHandlerContact = row.Cells(20).Value
      
    SQL = " INSERT INTO [TESTDB].[dbo].[tbl_MN_Daily_SLA] " _
    & " Values('" & RequestID & "' , '" & IssuingCountryName & "' , '" & ProgramStructure & "' , '" & LineOfBusinessName & "' , " _
    & " " & RequestGrossPremiumAmount & " ,'" & RequestCollectionCurrencyName & "' , '" & Clientname & "' , '" & ROServiceContact & "' , " _
    & " '" & RequestEffectiveDate & "' , '" & RequestReleaseDate & "' , '" & OriginalRequestReleaseDate & "' , '" & RequestType & "' , '" & RequestStatus & "' ," _
    & " '" & RequestRejectDate & "' , '" & RequestRejectReason & "' , '" & RequestCorrectionDate & "' , '" & RequestAcceptedDate & "' , '" & RequestLocalBookDate & "' , " _
    & " '" & PolicyIssuedDate & "' , '" & IOAccountHandlerContact & "')"
    
        con.Execute SQL
      
        DoEvents
        Call RunStatusBar(i, count)
    
        i = i + 1
        count = Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlDown)).count
    Next row
    Loop
 
    Unload StatusBar

    con.Close
    MsgBox "Done Importing"
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider SQL parameterization, the programming industry best practice to run SQL queries from application layer code like VBA. As Jeff Atwood [advises](https://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/), *you should never, ever use concatenated SQL strings in your applications*. Otherwise, you run into the very issues you encounter such as dates types, NULL handling, messy quote enclosures, and others. ADO supports parameters via the command object.

```vb
...

' PREPARED STATEMENT (WITH 20 QMARK PLACEHOLDERS)
SQL = "INSERT INTO [TESTDB].[dbo].[tbl_MN_Daily_SLA] " _
    & "VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"

' LOOP THROUGH ROWS
For Each row In rng.Rows
    ' NULLIFY EMPTY CELLS
    RequestID = IIf(row.Cells(1).Value = "", Null, row.Cells(1).Value)
    IssuingCountryName = IIf(row.Cells(2).Value = "", Null, row.Cells(2).Value)
    ProgramStructure = IIf(row.Cells(3).Value = "", Null, row.Cells(3).Value)
    LineOfBusinessName = IIf(row.Cells(4).Value = "", Null, row.Cells(4).Value)
    RequestGrossPremiumAmount = IIf(row.Cells(5).Value = "", Null, row.Cells(5).Value)
    RequestCollectionCurrencyName = IIf(row.Cells(6).Value = "", Null, row.Cells(6).Value)
    Clientname = IIf(row.Cells(7).Value = "", Null, row.Cells(7).Value)
    ROServiceContact = IIf(row.Cells(8).Value = "", Null, row.Cells(8).Value)
    RequestEffectiveDate = IIf(row.Cells(9).Value = "", Null, row.Cells(9).Value)
    RequestReleaseDate = IIf(row.Cells(10).Value = "", Null, row.Cells(10).Value)
    OriginalRequestReleaseDate = IIf(row.Cells(11).Value = "", Null, row.Cells(11).Value)
    RequestType = IIf(row.Cells(12).Value = "", Null, row.Cells(12).Value)
    RequestStatus = IIf(row.Cells(13).Value = "", Null, row.Cells(13).Value)
    RequestRejectDate = IIf(row.Cells(14).Value = "", Null, row.Cells(14).Value)
    RequestRejectReason = IIf(row.Cells(15).Value = "", Null, row.Cells(15).Value)
    RequestCorrectionDate = IIf(row.Cells(16).Value = "", Null, row.Cells(16).Value)
    RequestAcceptedDate = IIf(row.Cells(17).Value = "", Null, row.Cells(17).Value)
    RequestLocalBookDate = IIf(row.Cells(18).Value = "", Null, row.Cells(18).Value)
    PolicyIssuedDate = IIf(row.Cells(19).Value = "", Null, row.Cells(19).Value)
    IOAccountHandlerContact = IIf(row.Cells(20).Value = "", Null, row.Cells(20).Value)

    ' INITIALIZE COMMAND OBJECT
    Set cmd = New ADODB.Command

    ' ADJUST COMMAND PROPERTIES
    With cmd
        .ActiveConnection = conn
        .CommandText = SQL
        .CommandType = adCmdText

        '  BIND PARAMETERS OF VARCHARS AND DATES
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("pRequestID", adVarChar, adParamInput, , RequestID)
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("pIssuingCountryName", adVarChar, adParamInput, , IssuingCountryName)
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("pProgramStructure", adVarChar, adParamInput, , ProgramStructure)
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("pLineOfBusinessName", adVarChar, adParamInput, , LineOfBusinessName)
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("pRequestGrossPremiumAmount", adVarChar, adParamInput, , RequestGrossPremiumAmount)
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("pRequestCollectionCurrencyName", adVarChar, adParamInput, , RequestCollectionCurrencyName)
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("pClientname", adVarChar, adParamInput, , Clientname)
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("pROServiceContact", adVarChar, adParamInput, , ROServiceContact)
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("pRequestEffectiveDate", adDate, adParamInput, , RequestEffectiveDate)
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("pRequestReleaseDate", adDate, adParamInput, , RequestReleaseDate)
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("pOriginalRequestReleaseDate", adDate, adParamInput, , OriginalRequestReleaseDate)
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("pRequestType", adVarChar, adParamInput, , RequestType)
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("pRequestStatus", adVarChar, adParamInput, , RequestStatus)
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("pRequestRejectDate", adDate, adParamInput, , RequestRejectDate)
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("pRequestRejectReason", adVarChar, adParamInput, , RequestRejectReason)
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("pRequestCorrectionDate", adDate, adParamInput, , RequestCorrectionDate)
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("pRequestAcceptedDate", adDate, adParamInput, , RequestAcceptedDate)
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("pRequestLocalBookDate", adDate, adParamInput, , RequestLocalBookDate)
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("pPolicyIssuedDate", adDate, adParamInput, , PolicyIssuedDate)
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("pIOAccountHandlerContact", adVarChar, adParamInput, , IOAccountHandlerContact)

        '  EXECUTE ACTION
        .Execute
    End With
   
    Set cmd = Nothing
Next row
```

Comment: Works like magic! Thanks alot @Parfait. Just a question when I have blank cell on column that was a Date, it gives me an error of "Application uses a value of the wrong type for the current operation."

Comment: Also, if the cell is blank the next succeeding cell will be blank too :(

Comment: See update to nullify empty cells where you pass `Null`  as parameter value.